# Use unique user number in Google Forms

Tags: forms, url, unique, spreadsheet

I want to send my clients in my database an e-mail with a request to fill in a Google form to research their needs for our service in the future.

Every client has an unique ID already (for example EX0258, EA1405, EZ2815). I need a way how I can add this unique number in the spreadsheet that they will fill in. Of course, I can ask them to provide them by themselves, but this can cause mistakes in the information.

What I am looking for is a unique URL for each user that provides the Google Form Spreadsheet with that unqiue user ID. I hope you understand my question and that you can help me out with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the id ready to go from your db you can do it via Google Forms, but it seems the process cannot be automated (see https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160000?hl=en)

If you are open to a 3rd party solution, you could do this with Cloud Snippets via cloudward.com.  You could just include the id as a parameter like this:

your_domain_here.com/page_name.html?unique_id=ABCD1234

The code would look something like this:

`<# start form for google spreadsheet "Your Spreadsheet Name";#>
    <input type="text" <# your_column_name #> value="<#[url.unique_id]#>">
    <input type="text" <# your_column_name2 #>>
<# end form #>`

The unique ID in the snippet above would be ABCD1234

Comment: Sorry for this extreme delayed thank you, but, THANK YOU!